# WPF ItemsControl Grouping

Tags: wpf, grouping, itemscontrol

View class has `ID`, `Link`, `Name` and `Prop` properties. Some data is fetched from SQL Server to `ObservableCollection` and processed in view class to separate them into `ID`, `Name`, `Prop`. With this process I have a data like this in `ObservableCollection`:

```
2011 xxx item with property yyy
2012 xxx item with property yyy
2013 xxx item with property yyy
2014 zzz item with property zzz
2015 zzz item with property zzz
```

2011, 2012, 2013, ... are `ID`s with Hyperlink, xxx and zzz are `Names`, yyy and zzz `Props`.

I don't know if it is grouping or something else but I want to show this data in `ItemsControl` like this:

```
2011, 2012, 2013 xxx item with property yyy
2014, 2015 zzz item with property zzz
```

How can I do something like that?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please, formulate better the question. Is that data a string? Is that data a class?

Comment: Post your XAML and your data items definition.

Comment: It should be a simple matter in your view model class to have a list property that does the grouping you want (using Linq or whatever).  Then, you can bind your ItemsControl to that list.

Comment: You want to look into CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions, System.ComponentModel.GroupDescription, and ListView.GroupStyle. I'd have to look up the details msyelf, but basically you define in the CollectionViewSource by what property you want to group (similar to sorting), and in the ListView.GroupStyle collection how a group heading is displayed for a given level of grouping, which matches a grouping you defined on the CollectionViewSource.

Comment: Raul: I edited the question to explain situation better.

Comment: Dave: I am actually wondering how to do this kind of grouping in view class